How to integrate command history with the Autocomplete method of the Questionary library?
So I am trying to take user input using questionary's questionary.autocomplete() function. I would like for a command history to be present to navigate through it using the up and down arrow keys, however questionary.autocomplete() does not integrate with readline and I could not find a way to make it so.
So how do I add command history support to questionary.autocomplete()?
Minimal code:
import questionary
import readline

commands: list = ['command1', 'command2', 'command3']  # Example commands
while 1:
    command = questionary.autocomplete('Input: ', commands, ignore_case=True, qmark='-->').ask()
    readline.add_history(command)
    print(f'User input: {command} added to readline history')


# Even though this is what we would do if we would have used input() instead of questionary.autocomplete() it does not navigate through the command history with questionary.autocomplete()

